# не работает кнопка dbleclick

Tags: javascript, функции, click

у меня вторая функция не работает dbleclick, а DevTools показывает проблема в строке dblclick = clickHandler; ничего не могу понять..

```
const $btn = document.getElementById('btn-kick')
     const character = {
     name: 'Pikachu',
     defaultHP: 100,
     damageHP: 100,
   elHP: document.getElementById('health-character'),
   elProgressbar: document.getElementById('progressbar-character'),
  }
  const enemy = {
     name: 'Charmander',
     defaultHP: 100,
     damageHP: 100,
   elHP: document.getElementById('health-enemy'),
   elProgressbar: document.getElementById('progressbar-enemy'),
 }
$btn.addEventListener('click', function () {
    console.log('kick');
    changeHP(random(10), character);
    changeHP(random(10), enemy);
});
$btn.addEventListener('dblclick', function () {
    console.log('extra kick');
    changeHP(random(20), character);
    changeHP(random(20), enemy);
});
 const dblclick = 250;
    console.log(dblclick);
    const clicker = document.getElementById('click');
    const output = document.getElementById('output');

 function createClicker(clickFn, dblClickFn) {
     let timer;
     return function (event) {
     const context = character;

  if (timer) {
    clearTimeout(timer);
    dblClickFn.call(context, event);
    timer = null;
    return;
  }

  timer = setTimeout(function (ctx) {
    timer = null;
    clickFn.call(ctx, event);
  }, doubleClickThreshold, context)
 }
}

  function onClick(event) {
    output.innerHTML = 'click';
 }

  function onDoubleClick(event) {
   output.innerHTML = 'double click';
}      

  const clickHandler = createClicker(onClick, onDoubleClick);
    dblclick = clickHandler;
    
  function init() {
     console.log('Start Game');
     character.renderHP.apply(character);
     enemy.renderHP.apply(enemy);
  }
  function renderHP(person) {
     renderHPLife(person);
     renderProgressbarHP(person);
  }
  function renderHPLife(person) {
     person.elHP.innerText = person.damageHP + ' / ' + person.damageHP;
  } 
  function renderProgressbarHP(person) {
     person.elProgressbar.style.width = this.damageHP + '%';
  }
  function changeHP(count, person) {
     if (person.damageHP < count) {
     person.damageHP = 0;
     alert('Бедный'+ this +'проиграл бой!');
  $btn.disabled = true;
  } else {
     person.damageHP -= count;
  }

  renderHP(person);
  }
  function random(num) {
     return Math.ceil(Math.random()* num);
  }
  init();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В строке const dblclick = 250; определяется как константа

Значение констант не может быть изменено новым присваиванием, а также не может быть переопределено.